# suggest a alternate query to improve the performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-tuning

```
SELECT
B.tblBooking_id,
F.M_Merged_CustomerId,
B.depart_date,
B.cancellation,
B.booking_num,
B.end_date,
B.date_booked,
B.booking_price,
B.tblBooking_Id as SOURCE_RES_ID ,
B.agentid,
B.is_insert_date,
B.is_update_date is_update_date,
A.Agent_Email_Address as agent_email,
A.Agent_Email_Address as agent_email_system
FROM tblBooking B 
JOIN tblAgent A 
ON B.agentid=A.agentid
LEFT JOIN  tblFactCustomers F
ON B.booking_num = F.raw_booking_num
WHERE B.agentid !=0 or B.agentid IS NOT  NULL
GROUP BY B.tblBooking_id;
```

Table used : tblBooking , tblAgent , tblFactCustomers 
Index are present in booking num and raw booking num

Comment: can we know the order of index columns

Comment: Does this even compile? You are having a group by on the id and selecting so many other fields that are not in the group by nor aggregative.

Comment: If you don't want to get records with id of 0 or null then you should have an "and" operator between them

Comment: `B.agentid !=0 or B.agentid IS NOT  NULL` is very likely to be wrong.  It will _include_ `B.agentid = 0` because that is `NOT NULL`; I suspect you did not mean that.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  We need to see the indexes, primary keys, engine, datatypes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that script will execute successfully as there's group by clause and no aggregate function used. However for performance measures please check the field value `B.agentID` and if there's no value in negative then replace `WHERE B.agentid !=0 or B.agentid IS NOT  NULL`
with `WHERE B.agentid >0` and create a non clustered index on `agentID`.